# PHP, Google Chart to Joomla website

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, google-visualization

I try to integrate Google Pie Chart to my Joomla 3.1 website in a bit of tricky way. The chart is going to take data from the database and show it on the front-end.

Instead of the standard way to put data

`['Work',     11]`

I put it this way

`["<?php echo $params->get('label_1')?>", <?php echo $results1?>]`,

`["<?php echo $params->get('label_2')?>", <?php echo $results2?>]`,

and everything is all right. PHP takes data from my administrator panel, where I put a value for label_1 and it takes result1 after making some calculations with data in the database. Everything works correctly.

The problem comes when for example I have no data in the database for $result2 to calculate while everything is ok with $result1. I made a switcher to hide or show specific parameters and made this code for it

```
<?php if ($this->item->params->get('cpn_1')):           
          echo '["' . $params->get('label_1') . $result1 . '],';
        endif;?>
```

but it does not work and I cannot find where the mistake is. This should check if I switched on or off the specific part of the chart to be displayed on the front-end. After I create the page from where the data should be taken from database I switch on the piece of the chart from my back-end and it should work.

I also consider there should be a better way to do all this. The problem is that this is going to be a module and in case some day some tables or columns from database will be empty the page will not load at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a module it will definitely not be $this->item->params but just $params eg:

```
<?php if ($params->get('cpn_1')):           
    echo '["' . $params->get('label_1') . '", ' . $result1 . '],';
endif;?>
```

Edit: Also you where missing quote-marks and a comma after label1.